# Selenium Jenkins chromewebdriver version error

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, jenkins, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium test running in Jenkins with those configuration:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options
```

So far the tasks worked just fine and I was able to target the correct version of chromedriver binary.

but today all my pipeline start failing throwing the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 95
Current browser version is 93.0.4577.63 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

So far so good, beecause I understand that in my `/usr/bin` I am running the chromedriver 93.

so I downloaded the version 95 from here:

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=95.0.4638.17/

and unzipped the content in the same directory, I changed the name of the old chromedriver to `chromedriver.old` and made sure that I have the new binary in that folder.

But still I am getting the same error.

Here I am a bit confused. the error states that the binary is called `google-chrome` but I am not sure if I rename the new `chromedriver` to `google-chrome`it might break something.

Did anyone ever faced this sort of error?

UPDATE:
I notice something that I cannot understand.

My Jenkins throws this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 95
Current browser version is 94.0.4606.81 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

but if I ssh inside my ubuntu server and run this command

```
~$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63 (ff5c0da2ec0adeaed5550e6c7e98417dac77d98a-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#1135})
```

I see a discrepancy between the 2 logs. On my vm I have a specific version of chrome driver that does not match the one stated by Jenkins (based on my chrome option). So I tried to upgrade `google-chrome` to match the version 95. But the latest stable version is 94.

Answer (score 0):

You already had a Chromedriver that supports Chrome 95.

Now need to upgrade the chrome binary to 95 or downgrade the Chromedriver to 93.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did downgrade Chromedriver to 93. But the error is the same